# Convert Algorithm using Array index starting at 1

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have the pseudocode for a recursive algorithm that finds the k-th largest number in an array. The pseudocode uses arrays that start at index 1 but I need the array to start at index 0 for when I actually write the code. I cannot figure out how to adjust the algorithm to do this.

```
Select-kth-Algorithm4(A: array [1…n] of n distinct integers; left, right, k: integers between 1 and n)
pivotIndex = a randomly generated integer such that left≤pivotIndex≤right
pivotNewIndex = partition(A, left, right, pivotIndex)
if pivotNewIndex−left≥k then
    return Select-kth-Algorithm4(A, left, pivotNewIndex−1, k)
else if pivotNewIndex−left=k−1 then
    return A[pivotNewIndex]
else
    return Select-kth-Algorithm4(A, pivotNewIndex+1, right, k−pivotNewIndex+left−1)
//(Initial call to this algorithm should be Select-kth-Algorithm4(A,1, n, 5) for any particular value of n.}

partition(A, left, right, pivotIndex)
pivotValue = A[pivotIndex]
swap A[pivotIndex] and A[right]
storeIndex = left
for i = left to (right−1)
if A[i] > pivotValue then
    swap A[storeIndex] and A[i]
    storeIndex = storeIndex + 1
swap A[right] and A[storeIndex] 
return storeIndex
```

I realize that no changes should need to be made to the algorithm, just the initial call. However when I do that it is not giving me the correct value. Here is my actual code if that is the issue:

```
void Algorithm4(int *A, int left, int right, int k) {
int pivotIndex = rand() % right + left;
int pivotNewIndex = partition(A, left, right, pivotIndex);
if(pivotNewIndex - left>= k) {
    Algorithm4(A, left, pivotNewIndex-1, k);    
}
else if(pivotNewIndex-left == k-1){
    cout<< A[pivotNewIndex];
}
else {
    Algorithm4(A, pivotNewIndex+1, right, k-pivotNewIndex+left-1);
}
}
int partition(int *A, int left, int right, int pivotIndex) {
int pivotValue = A[pivotIndex];
int temp = A[pivotIndex];
A[pivotIndex] =  A[right];
A[right] = temp;
int storeIndex = left;
for(int i = left; i < right; i++) {
    if(A[i] > pivotValue) {
        int temp = A[storeIndex];
        A[storeIndex] = A[i];
        A[i] = temp;
        storeIndex= storeIndex + 1;
    }
}
temp = A[right];
A[right] = A[storeIndex];
A[storeIndex] = temp;
return storeIndex;
}
```

Comment: It's almost the same.@jelly You can try to first implement it assuming the array is from 1 to n.You can post this code first.And then correct the code.

Comment: In `int pivotIndex = rand() % right + left;`,the range of `rand() % right` is [0, right - 1], so the range of `pivoteIndex` is [left, right + left - 1],not [left, right].You should change it to `int pivotIndex = rand() % (right - left + 1) + left;`@helpme

Comment: If you think the answer or comment of other's is useful,please upvote!This will attract more people to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything. The difference is in the root call to this function, where you call it with A, 0, n-1 instead of A, 1, n.

The reason is that the absolute first or last element are only used in the root call -- everywhere else, variables are used for the positions.

Comment: Okay I thought that might be the case but I keep getting a floating point exception when I look for k=1 (the largest). Without posting my code, do you see where that may be coming from?

Comment: Converting the for loop seems error prone: `for i = left to right -1` translates to `for (i = left; i < right; i++)` in C, Java, JS.... (the purpose of -1 is to exclude right)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to find the kth largest element in one vector.You can change `vector<int>&` to `int[]`.In my program, 1 <= k <= n,n is the size of the vector.For simplicity, I just use the first element of the array to partition.

```
int findKthLargest(vector<int>& nums, int k) {    
    const int m = nums.size();
    int l = 0;
    int h = m - 1;
    while(l <= h){
        int pivot = partition(l, h, nums);
        if(pivot == m - k) return nums[pivot];
        if(pivot > m - k) h = pivot - 1;
        else l = pivot + 1;          
    }
}
int partition(int l, int h, vector<int> &nums){
    int b = l; 
    int e = h;
    int pivot = nums[l];
    while(b < e){
        while(b < e && nums[e] >= pivot) e--;
        if(b < e){
            nums[b] = nums[e];
            b++;
        }

        while(b < e && nums[b] < pivot) b++;
        if(b < e){
           nums[e] = nums[b];
            e--; 
        }
    }
    nums[b] = pivot;
    return b;
}
```